# send curl without waiting for response php

Tags: php, curl

I am currently working on a script and i need to make some curl posts. The problem is that the script will need to perform a lot of these requests which i am afraid will affect the performance and response time.Please note that i only need to make the curl post and i don't need the answer.
Here is the code I am using :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'api');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_close($ch);
```

Am I using the right code ? Will this code only post the request and closes and don't wait for any response ? 
Thanks guys for your help in advance.

Comment: If you don't wait how could you use `$return` result? If you don't use it then put your code in a background task. There's also `header('Connection: close')`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I just made the mistake of copying it ! Other than the $return is the current code doing the work ?

Comment: Whats it supposed to be doing? You got `$curl` which should be `$ch`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone check now ! it should make the curl post and don't wait for the response

Comment: You should use pcntl in php , you can schedule this job to worker in background, like apache kafka or gearman

Comment: return transfer is set to false so by calling curl_exec($ch); just a boolean should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function, this works well! :)

```
function systemCurl($url, $post_array, $headers=null, $check_ssl=true) {
  if(!is_null($headers)){
    foreach($headers as $key => $val){
      $head .= " -H '".$key.":". $val."' ";
    }
  }
  $cmd = "curl -X POST ".$head;
  $cmd.= " -d '" . json_encode($post_array) . "' '" . $url . "'";
  if(!$check_ssl){
    $cmd.= "'  --insecure";
  }
  $cmd .= " > /dev/null 2>&1 &";
  exec($cmd, $output, $exit);
  return $exit == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `shell_exec` function, then you can use this:

`exec('curl http://example.com/example > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`

Answer (score -2):

i would recommend you to use jquery  ajax so you dont need to care about processing time

```
$.ajax("yourFile.php");
```

where yourFile.php contains your cUrl php script with data

Comment: Hello, i am already using ajax but i am force to wait for the response of file.php because it returns some infos and perform the curl.

Comment: try to specify ajax property async: true it should run request asynchronously in background so you dont need to wait